# What does "pure, horrifying precision" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *Matrix (1999)*, Morpheus says to Neo about the AI:

> Morpheus: There are fields, Neo, endless fields...where human beings
> are no longer born. We are grown. For the longest time, I wouldn't believe it.
> And then I saw the fields with my own eyes...watched them liquefy the dead...
> ...so they could be fed intravenously to the living. And standing there,
> facing the **pure, horrifying precision**...I came to realize the obviousness of the truth.

What does "pure, horrifying precision" mean?

Comment: Have you looked up the words "pure", "horrifying" and "precision"? If so, what about this are you not sure about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to ELL!

We prefer contributors to use a dictionary before asking here. But as it's your first question . . .

[pure](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pure)
[horrifying](https://www.lexico.com/definition/horrifying)
[precision](https://www.lexico.com/definition/precision)

It means the precision was pure (unalloyed, undiluted, unmixed) and horrifying (terrifying, extremely shocking.)

There is a sense that the process is **[clinical](https://www.lexico.com/definition/clinical)** (second definition).